# How to alias in rethinkdb?

Tags: database, alias, rethinkdb

How to make a select alias in rethinkdb?

Example in sql:

```
SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a map

In JavaScript it would be:

```
r.table("table_name").map({
    alias_name: r.row("column_name")
})
```

Comment: If before the mapping I pluck several fields, after applying the map I end up only with the aliased field. How do I get my aliased field together with my other plucked fields?

Comment: You can do something like
r.table("table_nane").pluck("field1", "field2").map(function(doc) { return doc.merge({alias_name: doc("column_name")}) })